# Scraping multiple websites and saving the outputs in different text files

Tags: python, pandas, excel, beautifulsoup

I've an Excel sheet that contains two columns (`Url_id` and `Url`). I looped through the Excel file and used Beautifulsoup to get article title and article details from various websites.

Now I want to create a text file using the `url_id` as the file name, and then store the output of the website corresponding to the `url_id` to the text file.

[image: obnoxious screen shot; probably remove?]

1. The code is scraping all the data I need.
2. The text files are being created, but the code is writing same data inside all the text files.

[image: less useless, but still useless]

Everything is working well, except that it's looping through the text files many times and then writing same post title and content on all the files.

```
import os

import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Reading the excel file
data_ex = pd.read_excel('input.xlsx')
#Getting the url and url_id columns from the excel file
urls = data_ex.URL
url_id = data_ex.URL_ID

# print(url_id)

for url in urls:
    #Connecting to each url
    res = requests.get(url)

    page = res.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    #Title of each url post
    article_title = soup.find_all(name="h1", class_="entry-title")

    article_texts = []
    article_details = []


    for details in article_title:
        #print(id)
        text = details.getText()
        article_texts.append(text)
        #Post content corresponding to the url title
        article_writeup = soup.find(class_="td-post-content tagdiv-type").getText()


        for id in url_id:
            for story in article_texts:
                #specify folder to create files
                folder = 'files_folder'
                #Create the folder if it doesn't exist
                if not os.path.exists(folder):
                    os.makedirs(folder)
                # List of filenames
            filenames = [f"{id}.txt"]

           # Loop through the filenames and create text files
            for filename in filenames:
                file_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
            with open(file_path, 'w',  encoding="utf-8") as file:
                # Perform any operations you want with the file
                file.write((f"{story}\n {article_writeup}"))
            #print(f"File '{filename}' created.")
```

Comment: Post the full code, where is `url_id` defined? Where is `soup` defined?. Also this `filenames = [f"{id}.txt"]` is useless, if you only have one filename why the list and the loop `for filename in filenames:`?

Comment: I've updated my previous post with the full code.

Comment: Please i'm yet to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your **nested** *for loops* and what you are putting inside of them.

```py
for details in article_title:
    for story in article_texts:
        for id in url_id:
            filenames = [f"{id}.txt"]
            for filename in filenames:
                file_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
                with open(file_path, 'w',  encoding="utf-8") as file:
                    file.write((f"{story}\n {article_writeup}"))
```

Read it this way, for every `story` in `article_text` you are going to be iterating over every `id` of `url_id` and writing it to a file. So for just one `story`, its going to go through all the url ids and write the same story to every file `f"{id}.txt"`.

**EDIT:**

After reading your code I had to kind of guess what you needed as you didn't provide how your data looked (input) and how you wanted it to format (output). Here is an updated version based on your code.

```py
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data_ex = pd.read_excel("input.xlsx")
urls = data_ex.URL
url_ids = data_ex.URL_ID

folder = "files_folder"
Path(folder).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

for url, url_id in zip(urls, url_ids):
    res = requests.get(url, timeout=60)

    page = res.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
    article_title = soup.find_all(name="h1", class_="entry-title")

    article_texts = []
    article_details = []

    for details in article_title:
        text = details.getText()
        article_writeup = soup.find(class_="td-post-content tagdiv-type").getText()

        file_path = Path(folder, f"{url_id}.txt")
        with pathlib.Path.open(file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            f.write(f"{text}\n {article_writeup}")
```

Comment: Please i've updated my previous code on this question to include my full code. Please help me go through it so that i will know the exact place to implement this.

Comment: Its still unclear whats the input and whats the expected output.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, i've added comments to the codes....... I've been trying to solve this task for some days now and tomorrow is the deadline.

Comment: Please i'm yet to solve this.

Comment: I have updated my answer with code based on yours. I'm not sure if thats what you need but if you don't provide how the input or data looks like and whats the expected output then I can't help you.

Comment: This solved it bro, i really appreciate.